# I am wondering why my for in loop is not looping through my whole object Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting a false Boolean when each object does have name as a property. I consoled the prop var and got 0 back. What am I doing wrong and why is it not looping over every object.

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {

  for (let prop in collection) {
    console.log(prop)
    if (collection[prop].hasOwnProperty(pre) && Boolean(collection.forEach((item) => item[pre]))) {

      return true
    } else return false
  }
}
console.log(truthCheck([{
  name: "Quincy",
  role: "Founder",
  isBot: false
}, {
  name: "Naomi",
  role: "",
  isBot: false
}, {
  name: "Camperbot",
  role: "Bot",
  isBot: true
}], "name"))
```

Comment: Boolean(collection.forEach((item)=> item[pre])) will always be false as forEach array method returns undefined

Comment: Can you mention clearly what your ouput should be be looking like ?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a `boolean` so the loop never gets past the first iteration.  Use `Array.some` or `Array.every` to check multiple items and return from within that context.

Also use a `for of` loop to have easier access to items.

I am not sure exactly what logic you want with the inner `forEach` boolean test, so I removed it and just tested for property defined. This snippet should set you in the right direction, but add to that logic if you want to test for empty string, etc.

Finally, I added an `allPassed` value that is now returned from the function so you can track if any items failed.

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
  let allPassed = true
  for (let item of collection) {
    console.log(item)
    if (item.hasOwnProperty(pre)) {
      console.log(true)
    } else {
      console.log(false)
      allPassed = false
    }
  }
  return allPassed
}

console.log(truthCheck([{
  name: "Quincy",
  role: "Founder",
  isBot: false
}, {
  name: "Naomi",
  role: "",
  isBot: false
}, {
  name: "Camperbot",
  role: "Bot",
  isBot: true
},
 {
  role: "No Name",
  isBot: true
}], "name"))
```

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_, _"why is it not looping over every object"_ - How does _"use a `for of` loop answer those questions?

Comment: Interpret it as a suggestion. I think that's what it's meant to be.

Comment: _"You are returning a `boolean`..."_ - The type is totally irrelevant. `truthCheck()` doesn't return anything. Why do you call `collection.every()` `collection.length` times which only ever checks the exact same thing?

Comment: @Andreas Because it is not clear what OP wanted, so I duplicated his logic, and made a note of it in solution.  Regardless, his question, not concerning that logic, was answered.

Comment: Your answer also unnecessarily runs the loop till the end even when `allPassed` is already `false`

Comment: The problem was answered in the first sentence.  "You are returning from within your for loop."

Answer (score 0):

> why is it not looping over every object?

Because `return` stops the execution of the function. You have a `return` in both branches (`if` and `else`) so you end the function after the first element in `collection`.

> What am I doing wrong?

The `return` from above and you're looping over all elements in the collection (in the worst case) "twice" (actually it's `collection.length * collection.length` times). Once with `for...in` and once with `collection.every()`.

To determine if all elements in `collection` have a specific property, and if that property has a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value you only need a slightly modified version of the `if` condition:

```js
collection.every(item => item.hasOwnProperty(pre) && item[pre])
```

```js
function truthCheck(collection, pre) {
    return collection.every(item => item.hasOwnProperty(pre) && item[pre]);
}

const input = [
  { name: "Quincy", role: "Founder", isBot: false },
  { name: "Naomi", role: "", isBot: false },
  { name: "Camperbot", role: "Bot", isBot: true }
];
const result = truthCheck(input, "name");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of code:

```
let istruthCheck = (arr, pre) => {
  return arr.every( item => item.hasOwnProperty(pre) )
}

const arr = [
        {name: "Quincy", role: "Founder", isBot: false},
        {name: "Naomi", role: "", isBot: false},
        {name: "Camperbot", role: "Bot", isBot: true}
];

console.log( istruthCheck(arr, "name") )
```

Hope it helps... :)